# jQuery Mobile page not loading, spinning icon forever

Tags: jquery-mobile

so basically I've been making a jQuery Mobile site, I've hit a lot of speed bumps but as soon as I start making progress, this happens!

The culprit: http://www.ehustudent.co.uk/cis21318140/cis3104/cw2/find-your-nearest-jospice.html

Whenever you click on a link, it just keeps spinning forever. It started happening when I actually got the map to work! The map was inline, so I put it in its own file and it's still happening.

IT STOPS HAPPENING WHEN I REMOVE THIS LINE OF CODE

```
<script src="map-kensington.js"></script>
```

Please help me :(. I need to put that line of code in the body or the map won't load, but when I do put it in there the page won't load!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Find Your Nearest Jospice | Jospice Charity Shops</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=yes">

<!-- Start of jQuery External Links -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/jospice2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- End of jQuery External Links -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/custom.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="homePage" data-theme="b">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="grid">Menu</a>
            <h1>Jospice</h1>
            <a href="contact-jospice.html" data-role="button" data-icon="info">Contact</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
            <h2>Find Your Nearest...</h2>
            <p>Use the list below to find your Jospice Store of choice! Click on the button to be provided with information and directions to the store.</p>
            <a href="map-kensington.html" data-role="button">Furniture Store (Kensington)</a>
            <a href="map-allerton.html" data-role="button">Allerton</a>
            <a href="map-crosby.html" data-role="button">Crosby</a>
            <a href="map-kensington.html" data-role="button">Kensington</a>
            <a href="map-maghull.html" data-role="button">Maghull</a>
            <a href="map-netherton.html" data-role="button">Netherton</a>
            <a href="map-old-swan.html" data-role="button">Old Swan</a>
            <a href="map-southport.html" data-role="button">Southport</a>
            <a href="map-walton-vale.html" data-role="button">Walton Vale</a>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's the same for every page, 7 hours left to finish the site, please help :(

Answer (score 0):

Your script is failing with a 'google is not defined' error.

You need to add google script references to the individual map pages

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
</script>
```

Comment: I just need to put this line of code somewhere that will work >                   <script src="map-kensington.js"></script>